# Can't search for existing values in database PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, codeigniter

This is my first time using CodeIgniter and php so I'm quite lost, what I want to do is to show a table with all the elements in the database and then search for existing products via input and submit button
but whenever I submit a query nothing is displayed.

This is my controller.

```
<?php
class HomeController extends CI_Controller{

  function index(){

      $this->load->model('HomeModel');
      $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
     // $config = array();




     $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);
  }

  public function search_product(){

      $this->load->model('HomeModel');
       $nombre_producto = $this->input->post('search');

       if (isset($nombre_producto) and !empty($nombre_producto)) {
           $data ['db_simbo'] = $this->HomeModel->search_product($nombre_producto);
           $this->load->view('HomeView',$data );


       }

       else{
           redirect($this->index());

       }
  }
  }
```

This is my model

```
<?php

class HomeModel extends CI_Model{


    public function getData(){

        $query = $this->db->get('db_simbo');

        return $query->result();

    }
    public function search_product($nombre_producto){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('db_simbo');
        $this->db->like('nombre_producto',$nombre_producto);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            return $query->result();

        }

        else{

            return $query->result();

        }
    }

}
```

And this is part of my home view which i think it's causing trouble

```
        <input name="user id" value="<?php echo $inf->id;?>"/>


       <?php }?>
    </td>
    <td>  <?php foreach($info as $inf){?>


    <input name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_producto;?>"/>


       <?php }?>
    </td>
    <td>  <?php foreach($info as $inf){?>


    <input name="proveedor" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_proveedor;?>"/>


       <?php }?>
    </td>
    <td>  <?php foreach($info as $inf){?>


    <input name="descripción" value="<?php echo $inf->descripción;?>"/>


       <?php }?>
    </td>
    <td>  <?php foreach($info as $inf){?>


    <input name="precio" value="<?php echo $inf->precio;?>"/>


    <?php } }?> 
    </td>
    </tbody>


</table>



    <div>
        <input type = "text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="id"/>

        <button type = "submit"  name="submit">Buscar</button>>[enter
```

This is where i add form

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url().'HomeController/search_product'; ?>" method="post">
```

[image: image description here]

I have done everything regarding autoload models and so on, or so I believe, I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: why do you have so many foreach?

Comment: do you have already a form? you must have a form and point the url of your controller in the form attr action

Comment: Would you pleaase check my answer?

Comment: Each foreach is in order to fill the table so each column will be filled with all the data available, and yes I have a form it goes like this <form action="<?php echo base_url().'HomeController/search_peoduct'; ?> method="post">

Comment: Have a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming on file and class naming method and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html#general-topics

Answer (score 0):

**Try it once..** 
You have formgot to add `form tag` and `input type`

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
    // $config = array();
    $this->load->view('HomeView', $data);
    }
    public function search_product() {
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        $nombre_producto = $this->input->post('search');

        if (isset($nombre_producto) and ! empty($nombre_producto)) {
            $data ['db_simbo'] = $this->HomeModel->search_product($nombre_producto);
            $this->load->view('HomeView', $data);
        } else {
            redirect($this->index());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model {
    public function getData() {
        $query = $this->db->get('db_simbo');
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function search_product($nombre_producto) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('db_simbo');
        $this->db->like('nombre_producto', $nombre_producto);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {

            return $query->result();
        }
    }
}


<form method="POST">
    <td>  
        <?php foreach($info as $inf){ ?>
        <input name="proveedor" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_proveedor; ?>"/>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>  
        <?php foreach($info as $inf){ ?>
        <input name="descripción" value="<?php echo $inf->descripción; ?>"/>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>  
        <?php foreach($info as $inf){ ?>
        <input name="precio" value="<?php echo $inf->precio; ?>"/>
        <?php } } ?> 
    </td>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <input type = "text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="id"/>
    <input type = "submit"  name="submit" value="Buscar">[enter image description here][1]
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean adding input type to every input, cause i did add input where i'm trying to make a search but i didn't add type to every input i declared

Comment: @K.vai you just add input type in only button type submit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller

```
class HomeController extends CI_Controller{
  function index(){

      $this->load->model('HomeModel');
     // $config = array();
     if($this->input->post() != ''){
          $nombre_producto = $this->input->post('search');

          if (isset($nombre_producto) and !empty($nombre_producto)) {
            $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->search_product($nombre_producto);
           }
      }
      else{
          $data ['info'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
      }


     $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);
     }
}
```

In your View try to change your form action url to:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'HomeController/index'; ?>" method="post">
```

In  your table try this code:

```
 <?php foreach($info as $inf){?>
 <tr>
    <td>
         <input name="user id" value="<?php echo $inf->id;?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_producto;?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="proveedor" value="<?php echo $inf->nombre_proveedor;?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="descripción" value="<?php echo $inf->descripción;?>"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="precio" value="<?php echo $inf->precio;?>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Oh thank you it does work, the thing is now at the beginning is not showing all the elements of the database, should i use another method instead of the one i was using before? thank you the query did work.

Comment: Just use only one foreach

Comment: I updated my code above for your table view just try it

Comment: hey thanks for the answers, i tried your code and it still shows the table with no data inside, i had to change the foreach for some undefined variable info problem so what i did was  <?php if(!empty($info)){foreach($info as $inf){?>

Comment: it is because no data were fetch from your database what you do is correct

Comment: i see so that means my model is wrong correct? at the moment i fetch data from the db my model is not doing it right ?